# Need help to edit this batch file with decimals

Tags: batch-file

Now I am almost done with my batch script from [Pick a line from text file and set it as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244487/pick-a-line-from-text-file-and-set-it-as-variable) , for now I am testing on one target host. Batch file have issues with decimals and found this good script from http://helloacm.com/math-example-using-windows-batch-script/ . I barely understand how it works but no idea how to change the final result of the last echoed "echo %o%"

Example:

- AllocatedBaseSize = 3931
- CurrentUsage = 94
- PeakUsage = 94

Here's the code from the link above, I changed the C value to 3:

```
setlocal

    set /a a=%CurrentUsage%
    set /a b=%AllocatedBaseSize%
    set /a c=3

    set /a d=a/b
    set o=%a%/%b%=%d%.


:work   
    set /a a=(a-d*b)*10
    if "%a%"=="0" goto clean_up
    set /a d=a/b
    set /a c=c-1
    if "%c%"=="0" goto clean_up
    set o=%o%%d%

    goto work

:clean_up
    echo %o%


endlocal
```

Now the problem is the script echoes "96/3931=0.02", I need to display the result as "CurrentUsagePct=0.02" or even better if I can display it as ""CurrentUsagePct=2.44"

If there is already a batch file here that does the same, will love to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /a currentusage=96
SET /a allocatedbasesize=3931


    set /a a=%CurrentUsage%
    set /a b=%AllocatedBaseSize%
    set /a c=3

    set /a d=a*10000/b
    IF "%d:~1%"=="" SET d=0%d%
    IF "%d:~2%"=="" SET d=0%d%
    set o=%a%/%b%=%d:~0,-2%.%d:~-2%%%
    ECHO %o%
    ECHO CurrentUsagePct=%d:~0,-2%.%d:~-2%%%
    SET "CurrentUsagePct=%d:~0,-2%.%d:~-2%%%"
    echo %CurrentUsagePct%

GOTO :eof
```

Like this?

Note that `"quoting the SET argument"` ensures that stray trailing  spaces are not included in the value assigned.

Comment: Instead of echoing the result, I wanted to use it as variable. Changed the line to 'SET /a CurrentUsagePct=%d:~0,-2%.%d:~-2%%%' , it worked but I got _Missing operator_ console message. 

Looks like I need parenthesis, placing '(' after the '=' and at the end doesn't work.

Comment: `SET /A` means set to the result of an arithmetic expression. Batch can't handle decimals. I'll add the method to the code.